# Why I'm getting error "canvas.setAttribute is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Why I'm getting error "canvas.setAttribute is not a function" when I used

`document.getElementsByClassName("canvas");`

but when changed to

`document.getElementById("canvas1");`

it works fine.

Code:

```
(function setCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas");
    var x = 250;
    var y = 250;
    // set width and height of canvas
    canvas.setAttribute("style", "height:" + x + "px;" + " width:" + y + "px;");

    console.log("canvas width " + y);
    console.log("canvas height " + x);
}());
```

Comment: notice `s` in method name - `getElements` - it returns array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *list* of elements, not a single element.

Answer (score 1):

getElementByClassName return array type; use this code:

```
(function setCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas");
    var x = 250;
    var y = 250;
    // set width and height of canvas
    canvas[0].setAttribute("style", "height:" + x + "px;" + " width:" + y + "px;");

    console.log("canvas width " + y);
    console.log("canvas height " + x);
}());
```